# Installation of GNU Octave; path errors

Tags: install-from-source, octave

I installed Octave via:

```
cd /tmp
wget -c ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf octave*.tar.gz
mv octave* octave && sudo mv octave /opt
sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/octave
./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/hdf5/serial JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386'
make
sudo make install DESTDIR=/opt/octave/build
```

The `DESTDIR` variable was originally set to `/usr/local/share/octave`, with the same problem encountered when the executable file was run. The problem is that running the executable file `/opt/octave/build/usr/local/bin/octave` gives the error:

```
➜  octave  '/opt/octave/build/usr/local/bin/octave' 
octave: failed to exec '/usr/local/libexec/octave/4.0.0/exec/i686-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui'
```

the obvious solution would be to move the contents of `/opt/octave/build` to `/`, hence changing the executable's path to `/usr/local/bin/octave`. But I am trying to create a binary directory that can be moved anywhere on one's file system and still work.

But I would also like to be told how to install Octave (in a way that isn't moveable like a binary package) on my system. If it is the way I suggested, i.e., moving the contents of `/opt/octave/build` to `/` please tell me how to from the command line, please.

Comment: A better approach would probably be to use the `--prefix`, `--exec-prefix`, and/or `--libexecdir` etc. options to the `./configure` script intsead of simply setting the `DESTDIR` when you `make install`. You can run `./configure --help` for a full list of the supported options.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you should build Octave with `--prefix=DIR` rather than specifying `DESTDIR=DIR` on the `make install` command, as was already indicated in the comments.

Your more fundamental question is how to create a binary installation of Octave that can be moved anywhere on the filesystem and still be fully functional. And the answer is that it is currently not possible to do that. When Octave is compiled, several paths to its own libraries and scripts are compiled into the executable so it can find its own runtime. Some of those may be able to be overridden (see for example `octave --help` for some options to override default paths), but some current cannot, such as the path to `mkoctfile` or `octave-gui`. The locations of these helper programs depend completely on the value given to `--prefix` when Octave is built.